# Jquery watch certain fields for certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some test code here

```
<input type="radio" name="group1">1
<input type="radio" name="group1">2
<input type="radio" name="group1">3
<br>
<input type="text" name="text1">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2">1
<input type="radio" name="group2">2
<input type="radio" name="group2">3
<br>
<input disabled type="submit">
```

Please can you tell me if there is a way to watch multiple fields so that if their values changes i can enable a button..

So in short instead of having 3 .change rules watching each other... can't i do one piece of code that watches all 3 and if the values equals a particular something it enables the submit button ?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Please clarify the point of "_if the values equals a particular something it enables the submit button_". will it be a fixed value, one value for them all, a different value for each control, or even depending on the current item. ?

Comment: You may want to use proper markup, attributes, element termination, this markup is asking the browser to make a series of assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i correct understood ur question, here it is:

set classes (for less JS code):

```
<input type="radio" class="g1-1" name="group1">1
<input type="radio" class="g1-2" name="group1">2
<input type="radio" class="g1-3" name="group1">3
<br>
<input type="text" class="text" name="text1">
<br>
<input type="radio" class="g2-1" name="group2">1
<input type="radio" class="g2-2" name="group2">2
<input type="radio" class="g2-3" name="group2">3
<br>
<input disabled type="submit">
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('input').click( function(){
        if ( ($('.g1-2').is(':checked')) && ($('.g2-1').is(':checked')) && ($('.text').val()=="ok" ))
        {
            // event
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(':radio').change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'group2')
        $(':submit').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: This will be fired even if the user changes the value and returned back to the original one, which is not what he is asking for.

Comment: there are some serious assumptions going on.  all he asked was to be able to do something when a value changes, he didn't give a specification regarding the workflow or how.  maybe i should have written pseudocode, so you guys didn't take it so literally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the click event hander. For e.g.:

```
$(":radio[name='group1'],:radio[name='group2'],:radio[name='group3']").live("click",function(){
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a candidate for http://knockoutjs.com/ - You associate DOM elements with a client-side view model. When the data model's state changes, the UI updates automatically.

Comment: as much as I enjoy Knockout it might be a little overkill for this situation ... ?  Either way everyone should learn Knockout.

Comment: Seems like a little overkill if the scenario presented is the only use case.

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery selector matches more than one element, when you bind a callback function to an event, that function will be bound to **all** the elements the selector matches.

Example:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('body').append('changed');
});
```

See a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JpdAg/)